# Why is Transmission constantly active?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, networking, transmission, little-snitch

I am using Transmission (1.92, the latest version) in Mac OS X 10.6.2 Snow Leopard, and have noticed that, without any torrents (at all, not even paused), Little Snitch reports constant activity from it. What's going on? I'd always assumed when I saw that with Torrents loaded but inactive, it had to do with the DHT, or some such kind of scanning activity. But what could it be doing when no torrents are loaded at all?

Transmission:

[image]

Little Snitch:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a good explanation](http://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=8500#p40043) of what you're probably witnessing from the forums at transmissionbt.com.

Basically, if you ever hit a tracker they're checking back with you, as well as any peers that may have learned about you from past relations.  So even if you don't have any torrents currently loaded, they still know you as someone who may want to share things, and are checking.

Also, If you're on a dynamic IP address from your ISP, then you may also be witnessing traffic for people who previously had your current IP (if they were also using Transmission or possibly even another torrent client).